# How can I make gnome-terminal not transparent?

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-terminal, colors

When I use gnome-terminal the background is annoyingly slightly-transparent. Here you can read the ubuntu.stackexchange.com site through the background.

[image]

These are the background options I have, which are set to "not transparent".

[image: Options of gt]

I have the desktop visual effects set to "Normal". Changing them to None removes the problem, but obviously I lose out on visual effects like window previews, drop shadows, nicer transitions, etc. Any ideas how to make this background truly solid while keeping normal visual effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workaround for this is to set it to transparent and pull the bar to maximum.

That should fix your issue. :)

Like so.

[image]

Comment: :-O I can't believe I didn't try that. I was a radio-button out!

Comment: @richq its all good bruv!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug. Many other people have experienced it too. You can read more about it and find workarounds at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/561370

Comment: although it really is a bug, the bug you linked does not cover this exact problem. this is the correct bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/549552. it says the problem is fixed, but apparently the fix has not hit the repositories yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you encountered this problem with one of the Ubuntu themes. GNOME Terminal will use the background from the theme, and some of the Ubuntu themes (e.g. Ambiance) specify a transparent background for the terminal. You can change this but you need to change a gconf setting which means using gconf-editor (a GUI program) or gconftool (a command line program).

Using [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor), go to /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_background and set it to false.

Alternatively, in a terminal window, type:

```
gconftool -s /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_background -t bool false
```

The transparency should disappear.