# Middle mouse button emulation on Lenovo T431s

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I'm running Ubuntu (13.10) on a Lenovo T431s. Since Lenovo has removed the classic 3 mouse buttons on top of the touchepad, there is no middle mouse button any more. And emulating the middle mouse button didn't work, because it only recognises either the left or the right click, but not simultaneously.

Is there any way I can emulate an middle mouse button?

Comment: Pressing both the left and right buttons at the same time doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately not -- the mouse buttons are physically not separated from the touchpad itself. Instead, the touchpad is like one single big mouse-button...

Comment: Not the simplest way but take a look at the end of this page: http://askubuntu.com/questions/321727/ubuntu-12-04-2-on-a-lenovo-t431s

Comment: The design of the touchpad is the same on **Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro**, so the same problem there: [Simulate a middle-click on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro Synaptics touchpad](http://askubuntu.com/q/485863)